# URL is not accepted if it does not have http:// in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

Environment: RAILS 3.2.6
Gem: Devise

In my user.rb, I have the following:

```
validates :url, format: {with: NO_SPACES_REGEX}, presence: true
```

NO_SPACES_REGEX is defined elsewhere as:

```
NO_SPACES_REGEX = /\S/
```

The problem is if someone enters the url without http://, Rails does not like it, and it requests that the user enters a URL. How do I get around this?

Comment: That regex doesn't mean "no spaces". It means "there's at least 1 character that is not a space".

Comment: Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with my question

Comment: ... and it's intended to insure that the url has no spaces in it, while keeping the regex down to its absolute minimum, as all it takes is one space for a url not to be valid.

Comment: That's why I added it as a comment and not as an answer. I was simply letting you know that you have another bug in your code that may or may not be related to the question you are currently asking. Plug `puts "OK" if " f o o " =~ /\S/` into your console if you want a demonstration.

Comment: There is no bug in the code. "validates :url, format: {with: NO_SPACES_REGEX}, presence: true" means that if there's at least one space, then the url will NOT validate, and that's exactly the behavior I want, with the least amount of regex